# Display one value of duplicate and other values in jsp

Tags: jsp

I'm new to jsp pages , i retrieved values from sql database by inner joining two tables which contains duplicates and other values related to it.but, i need duplicates to be displayed once and other values in a row.these are the values..
"AndraPradesh | hyderabad"
"AndraPradesh | secunderabad"
"AndraPradesh | kurnool"
"Karnataka    | bangalore"
"Karnataka    | mysore"
"Karnataka    | bellary"
"Tamilnadu    | chennai"
"Tamilnadu    | coimbatore"
"Tamilnadu    | madurai"
"Tamilnadu    | salem"

i tried iterator and forloop for retrieving values from database to ... 
what i want in jsp is ..
 AndraPradesh | hyderabad"
              | secunderabad"
              | kurnool"
"Karnataka    | bangalore"
              | mysore"
              | bellary"
 Tamilnadu    | chennai"
              | coimbatore"
              | madurai"
              | salem"
plz help ...thanks in advance

Comment: how about using "SELECT DISTINCT" instead of "SELECT" to retrieve them in the first place?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: i used this query
SELECT DISTINCT s.state_name,c.city FROM cities c INNER JOIN states s ON c.state_id=s.state_id